# How to get my spayed 4 year old male cat to stop fighting the neighbourhood?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression

My cat has recently been making a nuisance of himself by fighting both neighbouring domestic cats and feral cats.  Not only has he made himself unpopular with my human neighbours (most of whom seem to dislike cats) with cat fighting noise, but he has also been scratched and bitten so that I have had to take him 4 times to the vet.

Trying to stop all this I have been keeping him indoors at night, but this is an unhappy solution as he prowls and cries and is obviously distressed even after 6 weeks of this regime.

He is normally affectionate with me and gets much attention as I live alone, but this fighting problem is disturbing and is a new phenomenon.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the only way to prevent him from fighting with other cats outside is to keep him inside. While it may seem cruel to deny your cat the great outdoors, your cat will be safer and healthier if kept inside. Ultimately this is a personal decision.

Comment: Is this the only thing that can be done? Is there no chance it could being caused by something?

Comment: @Henders No there is nothing you can do. Cats are naturally very territorial and they can get into fights with other cats when territories are not respected.

Comment: I agree. It's the simplest and most effective solution. They need to be separated. Unless he is put in a cat run outside.